# Is there any way to create AWS cloudwatch alarms in bulk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, devops, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have to create almost 150 alarms in AWS cloudwatch. I explore AWS cloudformation but couldn't find any solution. Does cloudformation supports creation of alarms in bulk? Or is it possible using AWS sdk?

Answer (score 2):

I have used boto3 many times to create cloudwatch alarms, works wonderful:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/cw-example-creating-alarms.html